# Install windows on external disk

Tags: linux, windows-8, usb, windows-8.1, elementaryos

I have a laptop (Zenbook UX32LN) with ElementaryOS system on it. I want to install Windows 8.1 on external usb HDD for gaming purposes - is it possible without interference in my linux installation? I've created Bootable USB via Microsoft Media Creation Tool - I've restarted computer, started Windows setup but after choosing installation type there was a message to remove bootable USB and installation will continue without it - but after doing it Linux boot like always and there was no sign of Windows setup.

Update:

I was able to choose the partition for the installation - but after choosing external HDD I've got a error message:

```
Windows cannot be installed to this disk. The selected disk is of the GPT partition style. 
Windows cannot be installed to this disk. Setup does not support configuration of or he installation to disk connected through a USB or IEEE 1394 port.
```

Any help/tips will be appreciated.

Comment: The error message (especially the second one) is clear enough. Unless you use Windows To Go which is a Win8 Enterprise feature, there's no official way to run Windows from a USB drive. There are ways to hack it and get it to work though so if you're interested you can search for the procedure elsewhere.

Comment: You might find this useful > http://www.howtogeek.com/196817/how-to-create-a-windows-to-go-usb-drive-without-the-enterprise-edition/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows OS on external hard drive](http://superuser.com/questions/960558/windows-os-on-external-hard-drive)

Comment: Is asking question earlier than given duplicate reason makes this question still a duplicate? doesn't given link should be marked as a duplicate of mine question in the first place? (Apr '15 vs Aug '15)