# Is it possible to run Windows 10 installed on a external HDD in different computers?

Tags: ssd, windows-10, external-hard-drive

Super User community.

**TL;DR: I have MacBook Pro Retina 13" as my laptop computer, and also a desktop computer in my home. Desktop has AMD HD 6950 GPU, will I suffer performance?**

As I'm a developer, now I need to have Windows 10 in both of my computers. I already have it on my desktop, there is no problem with that (although it is Windows 7), however I never altered booting options in a Mac until now (I had used virtual machine software in OS X).

The thing is, I want to use same HDD in both computers. I've bought an **SATA SSD** and an external hard drive connection box *-did I made something intelligent or dummy here?-*, as Mac's 128 GB Flash Drive does not fulfill my needs. The desktop also has its own HDD (not an SSD).

I know it is possible to install Windows 10 to this SSD and run on both devices, but the problem is, does driver difference make any kind of problem? I have an **AMD HD 6950** graphics card in my desktop, will my kids be able to play games without any hassle?

Performance is no object in Mac, SSD will be connected via SATA3 to desktop and USB to Mac.

Thank you.

EDIT: Oh, I forgot the Windows version (probably it doesn't matter), *it's Windows 10 Enterprise*.

Comment: Windows 10 Enterprise can create a Windows to Go drive.  I suggest you do that.

Comment: Possible yes.  Legal?  Probably not.

Comment: @Keltari Because a license is being used twice ha? Hadn't thought about it, good point.

Comment: Having just 1 experience and have been received 2 downvotes. Good for you people, good for you; keep it on.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run Windows 10 from an external hard drive?](http://superuser.com/questions/982577/how-to-run-windows-10-from-an-external-hard-drive), [Windows OS on external hard drive](http://superuser.com/questions/960558/windows-os-on-external-hard-drive)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called [Windows To Go](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831833.aspx) and is available since Windows 8 for the Enterprise Edition.

[Run the Windows To Go Creator Wizard](http://blogs.technet.com/b/canitpro/archive/2015/01/27/step-by-step-creating-a-windows-10-to-go-workspace.aspx), select the Windows 10 Enterprise Install.wim and create a bootable HDD/SSD.

Answer (score -1):

I'd say no, as it sounds like both machines have different hardware and thus both require different drivers. I'm not entirely sure if it's possible to successfully install multiple drivers of the same 'type' on an installation of Windows, but if it is, you'll more than likely have a very hard time achieving it.

Comment: Except it is possible.