# how to boot from a system that was cloned from usb HDD?

Tags: windows-7, usb-storage, clone

i cloned my 100mb partition and c partition into an usb HDD
when i boot from my usb HDD it logs into the original system

Comment: Try unplugging the original hard drive.

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense. Please try to clarify what you mean.

-You cloned some partitions to an external usb HDD.

Did you launch your system bios boot menu to select the USB HDD at boot?

If you did, then it is going to boot from the USB HDD.. and it should look identical to the original system (because you cloned it).

Comment: i cloned the 100mb (the partition that windows make while setup) and cloned the C: (system) partition into the usb HDD, i wanna run the windows i cloned on the external HDD

Comment: @dimmu read my edited comment

Comment: i tired that, i boot from usb HDD, but i tired to make changes on desktop and it appeared that these changes took place on the original windows not the cloned windows

Comment: Windows doesn't run from external USB drives, at least not when you just clone over to one. See [How to run Windows 10 from an external hard drive?](http://superuser.com/questions/982577/how-to-run-windows-10-from-an-external-hard-drive), [Windows OS on external hard drive](http://superuser.com/questions/960558/windows-os-on-external-hard-drive), [Is it possible to run Windows 10 installed on a external HDD in different computers?](http://superuser.com/questions/998742/is-it-possible-to-run-windows-10-installed-on-a-external-hdd-in-different-comput)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Because you made a clone the windows installation is still pointing to the original drive (probably your C:\ Drive).

When you boot into windows off your USB HDD, click on "Computer" after you have logged into windows.

What drives are listed?

You should be able to figure out what drive letters are associated to which hard drive.

If windows still has your internal HDD listed as the C:\ Drive (or your default window installation location) then that is why you are experiencing this issue.

If you no longer want to use your internal HDD at all. You can usually disable it from the BIOS. You could also manually take it out of the computer.

Comment: i wonder would it work if i switched partitions letters? , i mean if i named the cloned windows partition with C letter and named the original windows partition any other letter

Comment: @dimmu you can try to swap them. You would need to change the current C:\ drive to something else.. And then change whatever letter your external HDD is to C:\ I'm not positive if this will work and I'm not sure if it will screw anything up.

Comment: Why did you accept this as a solution when it has not solved your issue?

Comment: @Moab I think it did solve his issue. It literally does solve the issue, but he is considering different options on how he wants to go forward and customize the setup

Comment: no it didnt, i left the whole clone thing, i am stuck to ftp now, i wanna share my pc