# How can I create a valid partition to install Windows 10 on it?

Tags: hard-drive, usb, windows-10, windows-installation

I have a problem with installing Windows 10 on my computer. I have only an empty HDD (I want to install windows on it) and bootable USB with windows plugged into my PC. When I get to the window where I have to choose on which partition I would like to install my windows I get an error: "we couldn't create a new partition or locate an existing one". I have tried everything I was able to find on the web including:

2. Creating partition befor running the installation as described here:
   https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/asiasupp/2012/03/06/error-we-couldnt-create-a-new-partition-or-locate-an-existing-one-for-more-information-see-the-setup-log-files-when-you-try-to-install-windows-8-cp/
3. Changing my disc from MBR to GPT.
4. Creating partition during the installation.

And unfortunately none of them worked.

Does anyone have any idea what can I do to fix it?

Comment: If you switched the partition schema to GPT this means your system must supported UEFI mode which means the disk your using must contain the required EFI drivers.  Is that the case?

Comment: I switched the partition schema to GPT because I've read that Windows 10 supports only GPT. I didn't do anything more about that, what should be my next step then?

Comment: You read wrong Windows 10 fully supports MBR

Comment: You should answer my question about your hardware supported UEFI Mode or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to install Windows10 on the external hard drive connected via USB (which is unclear based on your description), it won't work with the default process.

This thread explains [how to install Win10 to run on an external hard-drive](https://superuser.com/questions/982577/how-to-run-windows-10-from-an-external-hard-drive)

EDIT BASED ON COMMENT:

If you're installing Win10 into a local drive (connected to the motherboard via SATA, most likely), then the issue is likely related to the BIOS's UEFI settings.  Access your BIOS and check that UEFI support is enabled.  You may need to update the BIOS to the latest version if it's an older motherboard.  The details and instructions can be found on the website of the motherboard's manufacturer by searching for the model number.

For example, hypothetically, if your motherboard were an `ASUS X99-A/USB 3.1`, you would want to visit [this site](http://www.asus.com/ca-en/Motherboards/X99AUSB_31/HelpDesk_Download/) to find the manual (including instructions & details on BIOS settings such as enabling UEFI support) and any BIOS updates that might add/fix functionality.

Comment: No, I'm not installing windows on the external hard drive, it's a normal drive inside my PC. I edited my question, sorry for not being clear enough.