# Cannot boot to a Windows usb disk

Tags: boot, windows-10, usb-flash-drive

I have legacy boot enabled and have tried to forcefully boot to it but it says: "No partition active". I need to boot into this to do a system repair.

Comment: How did you create the usb boot drive? There is probably a problem with it.

Comment: I created it with the dd Linux command

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/982577/how-to-run-windows-10-from-an-external-hard-drive

Comment: Thanks, that may help. Is there a way of doing it with Linux?

Comment: Legacy Boot shouldn't be enabled.

Comment: I couldn't even attempt to boot without it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this you have to have someone with Windows use something like Win32DiskImager or Rufus to image the drive. Then, go into disk management and set the newly created partition as active. After that, you can boot.