# Optimising speed for Windows 10 on an external hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10

I plan on installing Windows 10 to an external hard drive and would like to know how to make this as fast as possible. From what I can tell a USB 3.0 drive should be comparable to an internal drive, is this correct? Are there any particular features I should look for when purchasing a drive for this purpose?

Comment: Yes, look for an internal one, Windows standard won't run from an external. You need Windows To Go for that.

Comment: Yes, it will with some persuasion http://superuser.com/questions/982577/how-to-run-windows-10-from-an-external-hard-drive