# What will be the drawbacks of installing Windows 10 on an external hard disk (Windows-To-Go) performance wise?

Tags: external-hard-drive, windows-to-go

Will my system's performance be significantly affected if I use an external hard disk to use windows? The internal hard disk on my laptop failed; I want to get a new laptop but can't do so for a few months.

I have a Transcend StoreJet 25M3 hard disk (see [here](https://www.amazon.in/Transcend-StoreJet-USB3-0-Portable-External/dp/B07B4CJ4KS/ref=sr_1_4?ie=UTF8&qid=1526134977&sr=8-4&keywords=transcend%20hard%20disk&dpID=41H0YUuJ0iL&preST=_SY300_QL70_&dpSrc=srch)). I have it connected to my laptop through a USB 3.0 port. What will be the performance difference between using a internal hard disk (connected through SATA) and this external one?

Comment: Should be okay on USB3, its quite fast and full duplex. USB2 however wouldn't really be acceptable. Why not just replace the hard drive in your laptop?

Comment: The biggest drawback is you can’t update it, so you wouldn’t be able install the next feature update, due at the end of the year. Security updates can be installed

Comment: @mt025, Thanks. As for why I haven't replaced the hard drive, my laptop is in a pretty bad state right now. In a span of a year, the keyboard, battery, hinges and hard disk all failed. I just don't want to spend anymore on my laptop after all the repairs I did.

Comment: @Ramhound -- Yeah, I had that issue when I tried to install the April 2018 update. I fixed the issue by changing the registry key (changed the PortableOperatingSystem value from “1” to "0"), as given in an answer to this question: https://superuser.com/questions/1319046/how-do-i-update-windows-10-that-is-installed-on-an-external-hard-disk